# How to move cursor to specific word in current line in Vim

Tags: vim

Let's say we're currently in this line of code:

```
readonly L|a|zy<ICountryRepository> countryRepo;
```

and the cursor is in the position of letter "a", as shown in the code between two "|" symbols.

Now I want to move my cursor to the letter `y` of the word `countryRepo`, how can I do that using the minimum key strokes?

(Currently I'm using the key sequence of `fyfyfyfy` in normal mode ... Kind of stupid)

Comment: have you tried `$Fy` ? www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=152 is a nice plugin that shows you markers in your vim code.

Comment: The `;` is the default repeat movement command in Vim, assuming you didn't noremap `;` to `:` (common practice).

Comment: There are probably 10+ ways to do it and each situation is unique. Sometimes trying to think of the quickest way to do something (or least number of keystrokes) takes longer than just doing it the `stupid` way. It comes down to practicing the various ways to do it and your own personal preferences.

Comment: The cursor is not *between* `L` and `a`, it is either *on* `L` or `a`.

Comment: Should this be moved to Vi and Vim Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you know that it's the 4th `y`, you can do

```
4fy
```

If you know it's the last `y` in the line, you can do

```
$Fy
```

If you don't know at which position it is, you can still do

```
fy;;;
```

Comment: you can also do `fy4;`

Comment: That is, while a correct answer, a problem in need of a better solution. There must simply be a better way to do this in Vim, as it is not practical to count letter in the current line, both because one may count wrong and as trained readers doesn't read *letters* but whole *words*.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I would use

```
W
```

to move to `countryRepo`, followed by

```
fy
```

Answer (score 5):

I can think of:

```
4fy
```

But you should only do this if you are some strange robot.

```
/co<cr>fy
```

Which is one character shorter than your solution, but more easy..

```
Wfy
```

Go one WORD forward and then find y.

```
f>fy
```

Something like this I would do. Depends on what popups in my mind.

You should look into the [easymotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526) plugin, which helps with arbitrary movements.

EDIT:

easymotion is rather worthless here, it is more useful for jumping to targets further away.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `vim-easymotion`, https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion

You can do `<leader><leader>t` and then search for letter `y`. It's not that fast for the letters on the same line though. The real advantage is when you jump in the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

use **/** for search, then type your word and press Enter

however, if you want to jump to next word, just press **n**

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution! Thanks!

Comment: Also my need was to *jump to the next word that match a condition* (for example I want to move at the next "-f" in a long ffmpeg commandline). Then `CTRL-o`, `/` and `-f` find the first occurrence, and next, with `CTRL-o`, `n`  I move further.

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
tR;
```

or

```
WtR
```

or maybe

```
Wfy
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526).

In your case, `<Leader><Leader>e` then a corresponding keypress (in this case `b`) will bring your cursor onto the second y. Personally I use `<Leader>` as the easymotion trigger so it is only 3 keystrokes for me. The main advantage is you do not need to guess or calculate.